# AddFontResourceEx force selection of loaded font

Tags: windows, gdi

We are experiencing an issue with private fonts and seek confirmation of what should happen before we spend time producing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Scenario: You install ArialMT TT font into Windows. Then you call withing your code AddFontResourceEx() with the FR_PRIVATE param to install an alternative version of ArialMT. The latter is identical to the former except it has 1 additional glyph lets say. The second font file is properly formed / not damaged.

Question: Which version of the font will windows give you in response to the GDI call to CreateFontIndirect(). Will it be (a) the version installed in the OS or (b) the private version AddFontResourceEx() ?

Notes: Our current experience is that we are served the Windows-installed version from c:\Windows\fonts where we expected to receive the private version. Intuitively we expected that the windows font server would look for a match to our font request in the private set of fonts and then in the system font set should a match not have been found.

If anyone could point out the MSDN page that details the selection process steps that would be greatly appreciated.

[Edited to be less TLDR;]

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - what do the MSDN docs say?

Comment: This article is very old (Windows 3.1 days), but has a lot of good detail on the GDI font mapping process, including a table of penalty weights for mismatches:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969909.aspx

Comment: I suspect the system's font and your font score identically in the font mapping process, so the default is to take the one that's likely already in cache.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy great link thanks. I concur that 'select-match-already-in-cache' is what we seem to be experiencing. Couldn't give you enough points via comment upvotes so visited a few of your older answers.